# Mixpanel - query people (profile) historical data

Tags: analytics, mixpanel

Mixpanel. I have a profile property called "currentListElements". I update this value once a day for each user. Is there any chance to see in Mixpanel or get by API historical values (day by day) of this property?

For example to create a chart "Average list length of all users / day by day"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MixPanel People is auto updated each time you push data to it so you will only have a historic snapshot if you are pulling from the API at a standard cadence. If you are updating values on a 24 hour schedule, I would pull the data down into some other data source if you want to view that data over time on some kind of CRON or batch job.

Alternatively, you could post that update as an event to the Mixpanel Event service and visualize it that way.

Comment: Thank you. I need to find a way to achieve it using Events. It's not easy, because I need to be sure, that I send one Event per user per day.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively another option would be to have a property called something like `currentDictElements` that contains both the value you want to store and the datetime it was stored on. Then when you pull the data from Mixpanel you'll have the datetime when each element was added.